# Is it possible to style facebook share buttons or links?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, facebook

Is there a way that I can style how I want a facebook share button or link by using my own background image or simple image? I've been wrapping my head around this issue, googled a lot but I couldn't find any concrete answer. I saw that all the code from this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) is creating an iframe that I don't think is possible to style(because that was the first thing to try). Thanks in advance.
As you can see in my button I have the facebook link text over my background image. How do I get rid of that text and use a display: inline-block; on my link?

[image]

Comment: Ofcourse design your own ones.

Comment: How? I think you misunderstood me. I already have my own button design I know how to implement it but I don't know how to get rid of the facebook's link text or the image in iframe. Thanks.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've updated my question with my example.

Comment: And if I do that you think that my button will still work? :)) I think you're joking.

Comment: You can set the opacity of that iframe to 0 and put your own design behind it.

Comment: I need to style the link in the iframe, not the whole iframe, because I want to use display: inline-block on my anchor to be clickable all over the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the IFRAME, if you want to have a custom share button.

You would need to dynamically generate your own one like.

**WORDPRESS**

```
<a class="facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&amp;t=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Share this post on Facebook!" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">Facebook</a>
```

You could also generate it through the backend and serve it.

Bottom line, you can not use the IFRAME.

Comment: Can I make a popup appear instead of a new tab? and is there possible to change the image to be shared in the dialog. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could just apply `opacity: 0` on the real Facebook button and put your own design behind it with a little bit of CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <!-- your button -->
    <div class="myownbutton"></div> 

    <!-- real button -->
    <div class="fb-share-button"></div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}

/** position it so the Facebook button sits at the same location as this button **/
.myownbutton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    /** add your design **/
}

/** it still lets you click but you can't see it. **/
.fb-share-button {
    opacity: 0;
}
```